# How to update src of a img from javascript in a play framework project?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a image in my HTML file like this.

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/bell.png")" width="200", height="200" id = "symbolImg">
```

Image file is stored here.

[image]

**Output**

[image]

I was trying to change the image by having the following code in a typescript file.

```
document.getElementById("changeImageBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("symbolImg").setAttribute("src", "@routes.Assets.versioned('images/cherry.png')" );
    document.getElementById("symbolImg").setAttribute("width", "300");
    document.getElementById("symbolImg").setAttribute("height", "300");
});
```

But the image doesn't change. This is the output.

[image]

**Edit 1**

Also tried these ways with escape characters. Had no effect.

```
 document.getElementById("symbolImg").setAttribute("src", "@routes.Assets.versioned(\"images/bell.png\")" );
```

.

```
document.getElementById("symbolImg").setAttribute("src", "@routes\.Assets\.versioned\(\"images/bell\.png\"\)" );
```

Comment: Take a look at the rendered HTML in your browser. The path to the existing image looks pretty diffrerent from the path you've originally written ...

Comment: @Teemu How is it different? I pretty much copied the src from the html to put in javascript.

Comment: Only difference in the second one is it had ' instead of " . I changed that also now so that both are identical. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I meant the live document, not the file on your server.

Comment: @Teemu sorry I don't follow you. I am a beginner in this.  How do I check that?

Comment: ?? View the source, or use the Dev tools in a browser (hit F12) ...

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for the tip. This fixed it.    `document.getElementById("symbolImg").setAttribute("src", "/assets/images/cherry.png" );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Correct and long solution

All Play URLs are managed through the router, so you can easily find and change them if you need.

In Twirl templates, you can get URL as `@routes.Assets.versioned("images/bell.png")` because of the `@...` is a dynamic statement that [will be replaced by the server](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates), so it became `/assets/images/cherry.png` in the HTML output (well, if you will add `sbt-digest` plugin, as it must be with versioned, then, in production, you will get something like  `/assets/images/aaf512631818fb-cherry.png`).

You can not use `@` in the JavaScript client file just because it's a client and `@` will not be dynamically replaced (yet, you can use it if you generate Javascript file dynamically as a Twirl template, then replacement will be done on the server in a moment of generation that JavaScript file)

The correct way to use Play routings on the client javascript is to generate them and load from the server. It's a special case described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting

In a short:

1. create a `javascriptRoutes` action in a controller :

   ```
   def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
     Ok(
       JavaScriptReverseRouter("jsRoutes")(
         routes.javascript.Assets.versioned
       )
     ).as("text/javascript")
   }
   ```
2. Add correponding route:

   ```
   GET     /javascriptRoutes      controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes
   ```
3. Load the javascript routers

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes"></script>
   ```
4. Now you can use them in the client javascript

   ```
   document.getElementById("symbolImg").setAttribute("src",jsRoutes.controllers.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png" ).url)
   ```

## Incorrect and fast solution

Your solution is good only as a temporary fix

```
document.getElementById("symbolImg").setAttribute("src", "/assets/images/cherry.png" );
```

Be aware, in the case, if the project will run in a production environment with `sbt-digest` plugin then your `/assets/images/cherry.png` will be 404.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("symbolImg").setAttribute("src", "@routes.Assets.versioned('images/cherry.png')" );

instead of this try this

**document.getElementById("symbolImg").src='your image path';**