# Playframework: Call the controller's action by location.href through Javascript

Tags: javascript, scala, url, playframework

Is there any way to call `@controllers.app.test()` by the Javascript?

It has been working fine while using

```
location.href = '@controllers.app.test()'
```

And somehow this `location.href` became an actual URL:

```
127.0.0.1:9001/admin/@controllers.app.test()
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: You probably require this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting ?

Answer (score 0):

The `@controllers.app.test()` is calculated on the server side. Your HTML is in the view and processed by the server, that's why it becomes `/admin/@controllers.app.test()`. Your Javascript is just in a public folder, so it does not process.

What you can do one of the next:

1. Put JS file into the view (the same place where your HTML that "works fine" is placed).
2. Add JS object to the HTML like `<script> var myAction="@controllers.app.test()"</script>` and then use `myAction` in JS.
3. Use Java Script router:

   3.1. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting

   3.2. [Convert a javascript variable to scala in play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646563/convert-a-javascript-variable-to-scala-in-play-framework/48653029#48653029)

   3.3. [How to update src of a img from javascript in a play framework project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003005/how-to-update-src-of-a-img-from-javascript-in-a-play-framework-project/48006036#48006036)